# Can I assign a codename to a sheet when I create it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a new worksheet. The name of the sheet is in the variable "SheetName" and this works fine. Now I want to also add a CodeName when I create that sheet. Is this possible.

Here is the code snippet

Varables  SheetName and NameVar are typed strings

````
    If sheetExists Then
        MsgBox "The sheet exists."
    Else
        Set NewWs = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        NewWs.Name = SheetName
        NewWs.CodeName = NameVar  'This does not work
    End If```
````

Comment: Alternatively (and simpler) - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-you-assign-a-codename-when-adding-a-worksheet/fb400271-360a-4fb4-a509-a96dc1ac572e

Comment: @Tim Williams. That link almost helped when I added the line: ```NewWs.[_CodeName] = "myName"``` that worked but when I put "myName in a string var the code errored .  ```NewWs.[_CodeName] = myCodeName```

Comment: @Tim Williams The error is Run-time error 50132. Method '_CodeName' of object '_Workshee' failed

Comment: FIXED  Forgot Codenames must start with a letter

Comment: Use `NewWS.Parent.VBProject.VBComponents(NewWS.CodeName).Name = NameVar`. Error `50132` occurs when the code name is invalid, while error `32813` occurs when the code name already exists.